# Elasticsearch Tire Carrierwave remote upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, tire

I'm desperately don't success to make Carrierwave working with Tire (Elasticsearch gem).

I have a Question model which was an ActiveRecord one, but I migrated it on Elasticsearch with Tire. Until it was on ActiveRecord everything was working great. But not anymore.

What I want is to upload a remote file (from Facebook) to a S3 bucket. All config files are correct (as it was working under ActiveRecord model)

Here is my Question model:

```
class Question

    include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    extend CarrierWave::Mount

    include Tire::Model::Callbacks
    include Tire::Model::Persistence

    # set fields for carrierwave uploader
    mount_uploader :path, QuestionUploader

    validates_presence_of :question

    attr_accessible :path
    attr_accessor :remote_path_url, :remove_path

    property :difficulty
    property :question
    property :path

end
```

And then in my questions_controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

    def create

        @question = Question.new question: "How are you ?", difficulty: 3
        @question.remote_path_url = "http://domain.com/file.jpg"
        @question.save

        render nothing: true

    end

end
```

Elasticsearch record works, but no upload happens...

Someone has an idea ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After save callback should be explicitly called for non active record models, [as mentioned here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#skipping-activerecord-callbacks).

Like @question.store_image!

Also it may not be good idea to use path as file name, as it is confusing. 
For example: @question.store_path!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up using [Dragonfly for Models](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/models/) which integrated very well with a non-ActiveRecord model. I am using [elasticsearch-persistence](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-persistence) with a standalone persistence layer for models.